# Need help regarding .htaccess rewrite rule for query string urls with dynamic subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on a project and I am stuck with some `.htaccess` rewrite rule which is not working & I tried many things but no luck, so please help me.

Here is what I am doing:

when I open: `domain.com/us/search.html?keyword=xyz&location=alabama`

it should have to read the file `search.php` from root directory & work like this: `search.php?directory=us&keyword=xyz&location=alabama`

it's properly getting subdirectory, but not getting keywords and location data.

Here is my `.htaccess` code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-ad(.*).html ad.php?countrycode=$1&title=$2&id=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ country.php?countrycode=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-author\.html author.php?countrycode=$1&q=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-author/currentpage=(.*) author.php?countrycode=$1&q=$2&currentpage=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/search\.html?keyword=(.*)&location=(.*) search.php?countrycode=$1&keyword=$2&location=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/search\.html$  search.php?countrycode=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/latest\.html$  latest.php?countrycode=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/submit\.html$  submit.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^error\.html$  error.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 400 /error.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant rule is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/search\.html$ search.php?countrycode=$1 [NC,L]
```

Usually [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) keeps an existing query string, unless you add one yourself

> **Modifying the Query String**
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.

To keep the previous query string, you must add the [`QSA|qsappend`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/search\.html$ search.php?countrycode=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This rewrites `search.html` unconditionally.

---

If you want to rewrite it only when the request contains the query string `keyword=xyz&location=alabama`, you must prefix the rule with a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with `%{QUERY_STRING}`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} keyword=.+?&location=.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/search\.html$ search.php?countrycode=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

---

P.S. At the beginning, you write `search.php?directory=us&...`, but in the rules you have `search.php?countrycode=...`. Adjust the rules accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

here is working `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-ad(.*).html ad.php?countrycode=$1&title=$2&id=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ country.php?countrycode=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-author\.html author.php?countrycode=$1&q=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-author/currentpage=(.*) author.php?countrycode=$1&q=$2&currentpage=$3 [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} keyword=(.*)&location=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/search\.html search.php?countrycode=$1&keyword=%1&location=%2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/search\.html$  search.php?countrycode=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/latest\.html$  latest.php?countrycode=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/submit\.html$  submit.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^error\.html$  error.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 400 /error.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html
```

`RewriteRule` directive is applying only to the **request path**, that is only to the `?` sign. All after the `?` sign can be checked via `RewriteCond` and it variable `%{QUERY_STRING}`.
Here is what you can see in the logs of `mod_rewrite` for the changed `RewriteRule + RewriteCond`:

```
[rewrite:trace3] applying pattern '^(.*)/search\\.html' to uri 'us/search.html'
[rewrite:trace4] RewriteCond: input='keyword=xyz&location=alabama' pattern='keyword=(.*)&location=(.*)' => matched
[rewrite:trace2] rewrite 'us/search.html' -> 'search.php?countrycode=us&keyword=xyz&location=alabama'
```

And for the back-references to the matched `RewriteCond` pattern you must use `%N` not `$N`.

Comment: Added this and its working now,Thanks for the help. `RewriteRule ^(.*)/search\.html$  search.php?countrycode=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`